# power int number while in loop

Tags: loops, pow

OK, so my task is to get a single digit from a natural number and sum the square numbers (Using function while, which means no arrays yet :S). For instance I type 123 so sum=1*100+2*10+3*1; However the problem is that the digit could be whatever. My problem is that the power rises with int but its like so - 1, 10, 99, 1000. The problem for me is 99. Also answer is looping but I'll fix it later. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int N,
        number=0,
        answer=0,
        a=1,
        i=0;

    printf("Type natural number: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);

    while(N>i)
{
    number=N%10;
    N/=10;
    a=10;
    a=pow(a,i);
    answer+=number*number*a;
    printf("%d\n", answer);
    i++;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it the other way around.  Don't make the input an integer.  Start at the beginning of the stream, get the character, convert it to an int 'number'.  Then do

```
answer = 10 * answer;
answer += (number * number);
```

This will build up your answer little by little.  Note that I am not sure that this is what you are asking for due to your example not seeming to match the code.

Let me know if this is off-base and I will update it.

Comment: Already got around it with round function :). Thank you for your suggestion though.